# Combine asserts in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test case like so:

```
class TokenGeneratorTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_genToken(self):
                """
                Test if genToken returns a UUID, if not, then -1
                """
                tg = TokenGenerator()
                result = tg.genToken()
                self.assertIn(type(result), [ uuid.UUID, int ])
                if type(result) == int:
                        self.assertEqual(result, -1)
```

I want to test if genToken() returns either a uuid.UUID or -1. Is it possible to do it with a single assert* ?

PS: I am new to both Python and Unit Testing, so forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: `getToken()` works completely randomly? Or generated value depends on some condition?

Comment: def genToken:
    if (someCondition):
    return -1
    else:
    return uuid.uuid1()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in having two asserts as you are doing(assuming that you catch `AssertionError` :) ). Still if you want you can combine them like:

```
# You can also use type(result) == uuid.UUID or result == -1
correctness = isinstance(result, uuid.UUID) or (isinstance(result, int) and result == -1)
self.assertTrue(correctness)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have problem here - because you can't be sure if your `TokenGenerator` is working correctly. It can always return `-1` and you will be happy that test is passing. You need to create two tests here - one which verifies generator returns `-1` and one which verifies generator returns `uuid.UUID`. And these tests should be repeatable, not random. How you can do that? You should be able to affect `someCondition` in your token generator from test. I.e. you should pass some dependency to generator, or set appropriate generator state before you call `genToken()`.

Comment: 'someCondition' = isDiskSpaceAvailable(). How do I affect this?

Comment: @iceman you can create some class like `Environment` which will have method `isDiskSpaceAvailable()` and pass this environment object to token generator. This will allow you to mock `Environment` class, and provide your own results for `isDisckSpaceAvailable()` method. Actually I think token generator responsibility is generating token, not checking disk space on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But what if genToken() is the only consumer of isDiskSpaceAvailable(). Is it then justified to create a separate class?

Comment: @iceman you should create classes to group strongly related code together (i.e. class should have [hight cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science))) - that's the reason of class creation. It doesn't matter how many consumers class will have. Good OOP design usually produces many small classes focused on specific responsibilities

Comment: @iceman one more point - unit tests should test classes in isolation from other classes and environment ([FIRST](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first))